# Android: Library for drawing Bar graphs?

Tags: android

Is there any free library available using which I can draw bar graphs in android. I want to draw bar graphs indside my layout not in separate screen. Is that possible or some tutorial available for that.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: You check this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android. I believe it can help you!

Comment: Thanks for replying. Which library you think will be easy to use and free. And I have tried one lib it open charts in separate screen. Can I embed chart in my layout. I want the chart t be inside my layout not in separate screen. For example I am showing charts in child view of expandable list, when I click on group name of expandable listview its child should have bar graphs in it. Is that possible?

Comment: Personally, I have only used the ChartDroid in the past for a simple app, and I can't tell you now. You could check the other discussion or ask a new question for a specific problem, and hopefully someone will be able to help you ;)

Comment: I think chartdroid wont be a good option as it require chartdroid app to be installed on phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK done it by using [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home). It is easy to use and has example and documentation available on internet.